# Allow me to clear most recent searches

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In Jobs when you search for a job it places the job at the top right under Recent Searches.  There should be a hyperlink at the bottom of this div allowing me to essentially **Clear** my list.

This could be as simple as wiping out the div via ajax and the callback could wipe out these records from the database making this very seamless.

Please implement this feature.

Comment: why do we need to see jobs related topics in the "hot meta posts" on main SO Q&A site? Still amazes me that jobs isn't on it's own site. This post popped up in "hot meta" box and there is no way to know it is not related to normal SO activities

Comment: Why??  Where have you been?  Jobs is part of SO, so its natural to show there.

Comment: missing the point. Sure they added "Jobs" but realistically Jobs and Q/A have any more of a  relationship to each other  than numerous other StackExchange sites that are separate entities

Comment: You asked "why do we need to see jobs related topics in the "hot meta posts" on main SO Q&A site?", my question is why wouldn't we.  Why is it okay if there is a Q&A topic on meta but not jobs?  Considering JOBS is on SO and Q&A is on SO.  All job related issues go to meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @JonH I'll be implementing this tomorrow.

Comment: @Dean whose your boss, you need a raise!  Thanks

Comment: @JonH can I ask the reasoning behind this? Will help dictate whether we do a hard delete or not!

Comment: Dean - Aside from security reasons, the nice thing you allow is the user is in the driver's seat, keep he/ she in control.  If you guys need to mine the data for some reason do a soft delete.  If you have no reason to mine the data hard delete it but I assume you guys need this data in the back end for reporting reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This now works... We went with a hard delete because if we start to use it for matching purposes you've given explicit intent to not care about those searches anymore.

Thanks for the request :)!

Comment: I agree with you and like that.  Cool beans, thanks for your hard work and dedication.